# Alpha-trimmed filter troubles

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to make an alphatrimmed filter in openCV library. My code is not working properly and the resultant image is not looking as image after filtering.
The filter should work in the following way.

1. Chossing some (array) of pixels in my example it is 9 pixels '3x3' window.
2. Ordering them in increasing way.
3. Cutting our 'array' both sides for alpha-2.
4. calculating arithmetic mean of remaining pixels and inserting them in proper place.

---

```
int alphatrimmed(Mat img, int alpha)
{
Mat img9 = img.clone();
const int start = alpha/2 ;
const int end = 9 - (alpha/2);

//going through whole image
for (int i = 1; i < img.rows - 1; i++)
{
for (int j = 1; j < img.cols - 1; j++)
{
    uchar element[9];
    Vec3b element3[9];
    int k = 0;
    int a = 0;
    //selecting elements for window 3x3
        for (int m = i -1; m < i + 2; m++)
        {
            for (int n = j - 1; n < j + 2; n++)
            {
                element3[a] = img.at<Vec3b>(m*img.cols + n);
                a++;
                    for (int c = 0; c < img.channels(); c++)
                    {
                        element[k] += img.at<Vec3b>(m*img.cols + n)[c];
                }
                    k++;
            }
        }
    //comparing and sorting elements in window (uchar element [9])
    for (int b = 0; b < end; b++)
    {
        int min = b;
        for (int d = b + 1; d < 9; d++)
        {
            if (element[d] < element[min])
            {
                min = d;
                const   uchar temp = element[b];
                element[b] = element[min];
                element[min] = temp;
                const   Vec3b temporary = element3[b];
                element3[b] = element3[min];
                element3[min] = temporary;
            }
        }

    }

//  index in resultant image( after alpha-trimmed filter)
int result = (i - 1) * (img.cols - 2) + j - 1;
    for (int l = start ; l < end; l++)
        img9.at<Vec3b>(result) += element3[l];
    img9.at<Vec3b>(result) /= (9 - alpha);
}
}
 namedWindow("AlphaTrimmed Filter", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
 imshow("AlphaTrimmed Filter", img9);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Leaving that to the [tag:opencv] vultures.

Comment: So you have both `element[9]` and `element3`, with the latter hardcoded as a `Vec3b`, and then use `c < img.channels()` when you _know_ it must be 3? That's rather convoluted. The sort is also convoluted. I see why you "need" it - you're trying to sort both arrays - but that's just a consequence of the earlier bad design.

Answer (score 0):

Without actual data, it's somewhat of a guess, but an `uchar` can't hold the sum of 3 channels. It works modulo 256 (at least on any platform OpenCV supports).

The proper solution is `std::sort` with a proper comparator for your `Vec3b` :

`void L1(Vec3b a, Vec3b b) { return a[0]+a[1]+a[2] < b[0]+b[1]+b[2]; }`